# Explanation of trailing character %

Tags: prefix, basic, suffix, powerbasic

In an ancient PowerBasic file, I found this in the code:

```
%AppendRec= 1% '^a    Write/Append Btrieve record to named file
%PrtBar= 2%    '^b    Print a Bar Code
```

My question deals with the numbers after the **=** sign. I assume the trailing **%** has a meaning, but I can't figure out what that meaning is.
I know that in QB, **%** denotes an *Integer* type but that normally leads the variable as shown at the beginning of the code lines. The trailing **%** has me confused.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is used to specify the type of the constant, so you don't have e.g. "1" evaluate to a float and then have to be converted to an int.

[This page](https://www.powerbasic.com/support/help/pbcc/constants_and_literals.htm) shows you the defaults that PB uses if you don't explicitly specify the type of constants.

Answer (score 2):

Like Charles said it defines the type as int.  Prefixing it with % like the variable on the left is defining a numeric equate/constant.  The page link is old now though and their new help is at [PowerBasicHelp](https://www.powerbasic.com/help/pbwin/)

Look for Numeric Equates and Data Types.